# how to filter the list using pipes in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

could you please tell me how to filter the list using pipes in angular 2

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvtqeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I tried like this

```
<ul class="user-list | filterlist:userenter">
  <li *ngFor="let user of users" class="user-list__item">
```

**Filter**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterlist'
})
export class FilterlistPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.filter(
      item => item.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1
   );
  }

}
```

But filtering is not working when I type on input field  ?

Comment: [Don't use pipes to filter a list](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: can you try out solution , also provided stackbiz for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qbrg1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

you should do like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterlist'
})
export class FilterlistPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!args)
     return value;
    return value.filter(
      item => item.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1
   );
  }
}
```

check for `args` is having value or not , and first time you are not going to have value for `args` ..that is a reason its not working

Answer (score 3):

We can use ng2-search-filter npm.
For more details you can go through this demo:
[Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-search-filter)

**app.module.ts**

We must install the **ng2-search-filter** package and then we must import it in the app.module.ts as shown below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// search module
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2SearchPipeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Angular Search Using ng2-search-filter';
  searchText;
  heroes = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', country: 'India' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' , country: 'USA'},
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' , country: 'UK'},
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' , country: 'Canada'},
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' , country: 'Russia'},
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' , country: 'China'},
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' , country: 'Germany'},
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' , country: 'Hong Kong'},
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' , country: 'South Africa'},
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' , country: 'Sri Lanka'}
  ];
}
```

**app.component.html**

**| filter:searchText** will do the magic of filtering.

```
*ngFor="let hero of heroes | filter:searchText"
```

So let's add it in our for loop in HTML where we are actually iterating the list.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="search-hero">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="&#61442;  Start searching for a hero by id or name or country">
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Hero Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes | filter:searchText">
        <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
        <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
        <td>{{hero.country}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will take care of filtering the data from the result list.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: This needs a code sample or something @vishal-biradir

Comment: The answers and comments above point out the issues with filtering with pipes yet we still see so many "working" solutions. And even this ng2-search-filter component using pipes. It looks like performance becomes a problem with around 5,000 or more items in the array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769748/angular-4-pipe-filter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196756/creating-custom-ngfor-directive.

Answer (score 2):

The reason Angular doesn't ship with pipes to do this, is because it will have terrible performance.

For every single row in your array, you will iterate the entire array. Repeat that possibly several times per second. This is not something you want.

Instead, declare your list like this:

```
allUsers: [];
filteredUsers: [];
```

Populate `allUsers` as you presently do `users`. Then, in every place `searchText` changes, iterate `allUsers` and add the matching users to `filteredUsers`. This way, if only five users match your search text, the template only needs to iterate five times.

Your loop becomes:

```
<ul class="user-list">
  <li *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers" class="user-list__item">
</ul>
```

And so on.

I should add that since I first posted this answer, I have also used the same technique whenever I wanted to reduce the amount of work done in my templates. I've found that having your template iterate only a thousand times can perform very poorly on older mobile devices and cause noticeable delays even on my beastly i7 development PC.

Comment: I like this comment but I'm struggling to understand how to "replace filteredUsers with the filtered version of allUsers."

Comment: @artworkjpm I think I worded it badly. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the filter to the `class` attribute..

It should be in `*ngFor`:

```
*ngFor="let user of users | filterlist:userenter"
```

In your pipe code (filterlist.pipe.ts) return the whole array when there is no filter set:

```
if(args === undefined){
  return value;
}
```

Comment: ohh sorry my mistake

Comment: it is showing blank first time https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvtqeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Just return the whole list from the pipe if the query is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Return all items if args is null.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({
  name: 'filterlist'
 })
 export class FilterlistPipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
  // added code
  if(args == null){
    return value;
   }
 // added code

   return value.filter(
     item => item.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1
  );
 }

}
```